# How to established a connection and not closing it after passing some time

Tags: java, sockets

Im developing a TCP socket in Java, and I want to make the connection between server and client open all the time until it has passed some time, and then the connection close and wait for a new accept, how can I implement it by a while with a timer? Also, can I make that if the client or the server has not made any coomunication after passing some time, then the connection close? 
I try to do it by setSoTimeout, but it only works with the accept, so is there any method that allows you to close the connection after some time?

Comment: Why would you want to close and re-open the connection? Sounds like a XY-problem to me.

Comment: *...setSoTimeout, but it only works with the accept...* this is false, as [the documentation plainly states](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout(int)) *With this option set to a non-zero timeout, a read() call on the InputStream associated with this Socket ... will throw a java.net.SocketTimeoutException if the timeout expires*

Comment: Oh thanks, I have just proved it and when Ive waited all the timeout time and the exception did not appear, while the connection was enabled .

Answer (score 0):

Try using socket.settimeout(time).
Alternatively, get the system time when the socket was opened, and the current system time, and if the difference is a specific amount of time, close the socket.

Comment: But setSoTimeout active when the socket accept the connection, so is not valid for me. And the second way, how can I add this to a loop?

Comment: @GuillermoFuentesMorales you could initialize current and starting system time outside of the loop, and update the current one each loop, while checking for the difference between the two to be a specific value, again in each loop